# Unicode characters in MATLAB source files

Tags: matlab, unicode, encoding

I'd like to use [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters in comments in a [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) source file. This seems to work when I write the text; however, if I close the file and reload it, "unusual" characters have been turned into question marks. I guess MATLAB is saving the file as ASCII.

Is there any way to tell MATLAB to use [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[How the MATLAB Process Uses Locale Settings](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/how-the-matlab-process-uses-locale-settings.html) shows how to set the encoding for different platforms. Use

```
feature('DefaultCharacterSet')
```

You can read more about this undocumented function [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-feature-function). See also this [Matlab Central thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/15423-how-do-i-determine-my-matlab-default-character-encoding-scheme) for other options.

Comment: Thanks. The page you linked says that, on Mac, Matlab decides on an encoding based on the system's language settings, and ignores the LANG environment variable. I tried creating a `startup.m` file containing the command `slCharacterEncoding('UTF-8')`, but that didn't seem to help, apart from making Matlab hang in the "initializing" phase at startup. At any rate, even with slCharacterEncoding set to 'UTF-8', script files still seem to be encoded using ISO-8859-1. Any other ideas?

Comment: @LaC: Unfortunately I don't have any idea about how to set the encoding on startup. There seems to be room for improvement.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, even though the problem remains unsolved, because it doesn't look like there's any solution.

Comment: `slCharacterEncoding('UTF-8')` is a Simulink (hence the prefix `sl`) function. That's why it hangs the system.

Answer (score 20):

According to http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/238995

```
feature('DefaultCharacterSet', 'UTF8')
```

will change the encoding to UTF-8. You can put the line above in your startup.m file.

Comment: Note that `slCharacterEncoding`, suggested in the comment above is a function which requiers Simulink.

Answer (score 2):

Mac OSX only!

As I found solution which worked in my case I want to share it.

Mathworks advises [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/slcharacterencoding.html) to use `slCharacterEncoding(encoding)` in order to change the encoding as desired, but for the OSX this does not solve the issue exactly as the `feature('DefaultCharacterSet')` in accepted answer does not do it. What helped me to get the UTF-8 encoding set for opening and saving .m files was the following link on MATLAB answers: 
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/12422-macosx-encoding-problem

Matlab seems to ignore any value set in `slCharacterEncoding(encoding)` or `feature('DefaultCharacterSet')` but uses region set in System Preferences -> Language & Region. After checking which region is selected in our case then it is possible to define the actual encoding in the hidden configuration file in

```
 $matlabroot/bin/lcdata.xml
```

This directory can be opened by getting to the Applications and after right click on Matlab by selecting Show Package Contents as on screenshot (here in German)

[image: Package Contents]

For example for German default ISO-8859-1 it is possible to adjust it by changing the respective line in the file lcdata.xml:

```
 <locale name="de_DE" encoding="ISO-8859-1" xpg_name="de_DE.ISO8859-1">
```

to:

```
 <locale name="de_DE" encoding="UTF-8" xpg_name="de_DE.UTF-8">
```

If the region which is selected is not present in the lcdata.xml file this will not work.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The solution provided [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/340903-unicode-characters-in-m-file#answer_274523) worked for me on Windows with R2018a.

In case link doesn't work: the idea is to use file `matlabroot/bin/lcdata.xml` to configure an alias for encoding name (some explanation can be found in this very file in the comments):

```
<codeset>
  <encoding name="UTF-8">
   <encoding_alias name="windows-1252" />
  </encoding>
</codeset>
```

You would use your own value instead of `windows-1252`, currently used encoding can be obtained by running `feature('locale')`.

Although, if you use Unicode characters in help comments, the help browser does not recognize them, as well as console window output.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS users, Jendker's solution really helps!!! Thanks a lot first.

Recap here.

1. Check the default language in Matlab by typing in the command window `getenv('LANG')`. Mine returned `en_US.ISO8859-1`.
2. In the Application directory find Matlab, show its package contents. Go to `bin`, open `lcdata.xml` as an administrator, locate the corresponding `xpg_name`, in my case `en_US.ISO8859-1`. Change `encoding` in the same line to `UTF-8`. Save it.
3. Restart Matlab, and it's all done!