# MATLAB plot special character "ā" using text() function

Tags: matlab, plot, text, special-characters

How to write special character "ā" on a plot using MATLAB text() function?

Comment: What is wrong with `text(0,0,'ā')`? It seems to work for me.

Comment: @CrisLuengo `ā` will disappear once you save your m-file. It follows a different encoding. This can be done though: `double('ā')`, save the result (`[196 129]`) and then use that with `char`. i.e. `char([196 129])`

Comment: @SardarUsama: It doesn't disappear in an M-file I created and saved on https://matlab.mathworks.com/.

Comment: @CrisLuengo does it stay as is if you close the file and reopen it?

Comment: @SardarUsama Yes, it does. Maybe it depends on which OS you're on? Or some encoding configuration?

Comment: @CrisLuengo For me, `'ā'` changes to `'?'` if I close and reopen the m-file (ANSI Encoding, Win10, MATLAB R2018a, Desktop version)

Comment: @SardarUsama You probably need to use some form of Unicode encoding. MATLAB uses UTF-16 internally (or is it UCS-2?)

Comment: @CrisLuengo I found the solution [*here*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4984532). I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49801069/5698672) to fix it. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LaTeX` interpretor for achieving this. Here is an example:

```
p = plot(1,2,'O');
hold on
pCS = plot(1,3,'rO');
txt = text(1,1,{'p';'$\bar{a}$'});
set(txt,'Interpreter','latex');
```

Comment: This will plot "â". I need to plot "ā"

Comment: The correct one is '$\bar{a}$'. Please change your answer accordingly. txt=text(1,1,{'p$\bar{a}$'}); set(txt,'Interpreter','latex');